# export function with different name

Tags: bash

I have a script that exports a function for child scripts to use and would like to change what function is exported based on a conditional.  I know I could just declare the two different functions within the conditional but would prefer to avoid that if possible.

So an example would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo () { echo foo; }
bar () { echo bar; }

if [[ $var == foo ]]; then
    #in this case my_func() should execute foo()
    export -f my_func
elif [[ $var == bar ]]; then
    #in this case my_func() should execute bar()
    export -f my_func
fi
```

I guess I could also just make a simple inception function like `my_func() { foo "$@"; }` inside the conditional before the export too but am asking if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Just trying things, not that I know what I'm doing... `foo () { echo foo; }; eval "$(echo "my_func()"; declare -f foo | tail -n +2)"; my_func → foo` (`export -f` closes my terminal).

Answer (score 5):

This may be what you were already proposing, but I don't think there's a significantly better way. The shell doesn't provide a safe introspective way of including the actual declaration of the pre-declared `foo` or `bar` functions in the declaration of `my_func`, which I suppose would be an alternative. And if you're not willing to move the functionality of `foo` or `bar` *into* `my_func` (i.e., without ever creating `foo` or `bar` as separate functions), then what I show here may be best:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

foo () { echo foo; }
bar () { echo bar; }

case $var in
    foo) export -f foo; my_func () { foo "$@"; } ;;
    bar) export -f bar; my_func () { bar "$@"; } ;;
esac

export -f my_func
```

That is, depending on the value of `var`, export the appropriate function(s) that your `my_func` is using and declare your function. Then export it.